# Removing lines if word exits and printing all lines between lines having two words in powershell

Tags: batch-file, powershell

### Question 1 :

I have a MAIN.txt file with some 2,000,000 lines. File will be in the below format

> unit=123
>   xxx
>   yyy
>
> unit=245
>   xx
>   yy
>
> unit=PO 789
>   x
>   y
>
> unit=258
>   xy
>   yx
>
> unit=777
>   xz
>   zx
>
> unit=999
>   yz
>   zy
>
> unit=456
>   zz
>   yy

I want to remove the line having word 'PO' and three lines following them.

**Sample Output :**

> unit=123
>   xxx
>   yyy
>
> unit=245
>   xx
>   yy
>
> unit=258
>   xy
>   yx
>
> unit=777
>   xz
>   zx
>
> unit=999
>   yz
>   zy
>
> unit=456
>   zz
>   yy

I am new to Powershell. I tried this but I'm able to remove only the line with PO. How do I delete n lines following it.

### Second question :

I have a file ,say `extractthis.txt` -

> 123|258
>
> 777|456

I want to print the lines in MAIN file between the lines having the number 123 and two lines after 258 (i.e bbb) and save it in a new file, say file1.

Then read the second line from extractthis.txt (777|n456) and print the lines between the line having the number 777 and two lines after the line having 456 (jjj) and save it to file2.txt and so on.

I have done similar thing in Unix. But I'm struggling to do the same in Powershell.

Comment: _I tried this but I'm able to remove only the line with PO_ --> Please show us your code!

Comment: Looking at your example for the second question, I'm not seeing the content other than the numbers, so I'm not exactly sure what to suggest, although by adding a few `if` statements to my other answer, you can probably get there...

Answer (score 1):

For question #1, something like the following function should work (at least it did when I tried it against your data file):

```
function Skip-Match {
[cmdletbinding()]
    Param(
        [parameter(Mandatory)][string]$Pattern,
        [parameter(Mandatory)][string]$Path,
        [int]$Count=3
    )

    $lines = Get-Content -Path $Path
    $state = -1
    $lines | ForEach-Object {
        $line = $_
        if( $line.ToString() -like "*$Pattern*" ) {
            $state=3
        } elseif ( $state -lt 0 ) {
            $line
            Write-Verbose $line
        }
        $state--
    }
}
```

You can then save it to a file (I called it skip-match.ps1), source the file, and then just execute the function... something like:

```
. .\skip-match.ps1
Skip-Match -Pattern "PO" -Path .\datafile.dat
```

Answer (score 1):

Given you have such a large amount of lines in MAIN.txt, I'd avoid using Get-Content as it will open the entire file into memory. Use streams instead.

```
function sanitise($file) {

    $reader = [System.IO.File]::OpenText($file)
    $i = 0
    try {
        while(($line = $reader.ReadLine()) -ne $null) {
            if($i -gt 0) { $i++ }
            if($i -gt 4) { $i = 0 }
            if($line -like "*PO*") { $i++ }
            if ($i -eq 0) { echo $line }
        }
    }
    finally {
        $reader.Close()
    }
}

function readBetweenLines($file, $a, $b) {

    $reader = [System.IO.File]::OpenText($file)
    $i = 0
    $read = $false
    try {
        while(($line = $reader.ReadLine()) -ne $null) {
            if($i -gt 0) { $i++ }
            if($line -match ".*$a`$") { $read = $true }
            if($line -match ".*$b`$") { $i++ }          
            if(($read) -and ($i -lt 4)) { echo $line }
            if($i -gt 4) { break }
        }
    }
    finally {
        $reader.Close()
    }
}

sanitise(".\MAIN.txt")

$extract = get-content ".\extractthis.txt"
foreach($line in $extract) {
    $lineNum = $line.split("|")
    readBetweenLines ".\MAIN.txt" $lineNum[0] $lineNum[1]
}
```

Substitute the `echo` statements with whatever you need to output the content somewhere else. As it stands, this will also require you sanitise MAIN.txt into a new file before running the line checking function on it.